# Как сделать, чтобы был перенос по слову, а не по элементу списка?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы был перенос по слову, а не по элементу списка? (как на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.list {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #828EA5;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item:last-child::after {
  content: none;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <p class="text">
      some text here
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p class="text">
      longer text
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: В зависимости от конкретной ситуации, помимо ограничения ширины, можно использовать `<wbr>` или `&shy;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.list {
  width: 190px; /* при 180 не увидите эффекта */
  display:block;
}
.item, .item p {display:inline;}
```

```css
.list {
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #828EA5;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item:last-child::after {
  content: none;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.list {
  width: 190px;
  display: block;
}

.item,
.item p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <p class="text">
      some text here
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p class="text">
      longer text
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```